# Identify Process using AMD-V or Intel VT-X in Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, system.diagnostics, hardware-acceleration

I want to positively identify a process that is blocking AMD-V.

Background:

Despite my efforts to resist, Windows 10 decided it was time to upgrade to 1903 and this has left VirtualBox 6.0 inoperable.

```
(VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API).
AMD-V is not available (VERR_SVM_NO_SVM).
```

I know that is somewhat misleading because:

1. It worked before.
2. It is still enabled in the BIOS (I double-checked).

and

3. I have checked that Hyper-V is indeed still not enabled (Windows 10 Pro). A previous update through me for a loop when it magically turned on, but this time, it doesn't seem to be the culprit.

I don't think it's a zero-day issue because the update has been out for a while. Just for giggles,  I decided to press on forward and install all available updates. Still no joy.

I'm starting to suspect that something is using the hardware virtualization and locking the resource. But what? And, how to find out?

Is there a way to identify a running process that is using AMD-V? (Phenom  II X6 1055T)

No joy from Googling - I only found heaps of articles repeating the steps above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is probably my last stop before I revert the update.

Thanks!

Comment: Application Guard and Credential Guard also use virtualization technology and may need to be turned off.

Comment: Thanks for that. They were off but I discovered "containers" and disabling solved the problem. I wonder what horrors await with it disabled. lol.

Comment: I'm still interested a diagnostic trick for that sort of thing so the search isn't such a random walk.

Comment: The future is called Windows Hypervisor Platform; foreign hypervisors can plug into this framework to enable co-existence with the built-in Hyper V. VMware, for example, has demoed pre-release versions of Workstation and Player which can work without disabling Windows features which depend on virtualization, such as App Guard, Crendential Guard, server containers and WSL 2.

Answer (score 0):

What helps me:

- I installed updates to Windows 10.
- I downloaded last Virtual Box (6.0.16)
- Turn Windows features on or off

  - Disable Hyper V, Windows Hypervisor Platform (may be I shouldn`t and last versions are enough.)